# airplane mode in wpa_supplicant

Tags: wpa-supplicant, nmcli, dhcpcd

I believe "airplane mode" on various applets is equivalent to `nmcli radio wifi off`. What is its equivalence when we use dhcpcd/wpa_supplicant? `pkill wpa_supplicant`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NetworkManager* (and its `nmcli` CLI command) calls a [lower level API](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RFKILL.html) in the end. As this has nothing to do with *dhcpcd* and not much to do with *wpa_supplicant*, if you're not using *NetworkManager*, you can still (install the adequate package and) use as root the [`rfkill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rfkill.8.html) command.

To list the status of all available RF devices:

```
rfkill list
```

To disable all of them:

```
rfkill block all
```

To enable all of them (only if no hardware switch prevents it):

```
rfkill unblock all
```

For other options please check the man.

Comment: Didn't realize nmcli goes all the way down to ```rfkill block wifi```. Thanks